# Add some text to curl's user agent string? (i.e. curl with a UA that includes curl's default UA & my text)

Tags: http, curl, best-practices, useragent

I am writing a shell script which uses `curl(1)` to download files. By default curl will set a HTTP `User-Agent` (UA) to something like `curl/7.74.0`. I want to be a good internet citizen and set the UA to say what my script is. Since the software that is making HTTP requests is still curl, I would like this user agent to also include the default curl UA.

I can replace `User-Agent` with `-A`, but is it possible to *add* something to the default curl UA? Is there an argument to prefix/suffix my text to what curl would normally send? (e.g. `curl --append-to-ua ' mysoftware/1.0' …` results in `User-Agent: curl/7.74.0 mysoftware/1.0` http header)

*(curl v7.74.0 installed via apt on debian 11)*